# Returning single array element using map

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to return a single element from an array using `map` but keep getting `null`errors

I have this so far

```
var [headers] = recNoteSheets[recSh].getRange(i,1,1,20).getValues();//get all headers
var tempPref = "test "//temp session prefix variable for regexp REPLACE
var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");

//get sortId (cue name) column
var indx = headers.indexOf("SORT ID");
var sortIds = recNotes.map(function(x){
  return regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1]
});
```

I'm confused as to why `null` is causing an issue as my understanding was the return will not return `null`?

EDIT

So added in the identical line before the return statement

```
  var testexec = regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1];
  return (regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1]);
```

The `testexec` variable is set fine and has a value but when the identical statement is run in the `return` it errors. I have no idea why

EDIT2

Still stuck. Heres a snippet showing the issues. The items in the array are identical but it gets stuck on the second. Sure someone will instantly look at this and see the issue but its driving me nuts!

```
function blah(){

    var tempPref = "Sess "//temp session prefix variable for regexp REPLACE
    var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");

    var recNotes = [["", 2, 2, "St1 Rhythm", "A", "AcGtrs&EBass", "top", "53", "", "", "", "N1", "Good Leo Sound", "", "", (new Date(1232449380000)), "", "Sess A1_01 Rec01 St1 Rhythm", "", "", "", "", "", ""],["", 2, 2, "St1 Rhythm", "A", "AcGtrs&EBass", "top", "53", "", "", "", "N1", "Good Leo Sound", "", "", (new Date(1232449380000)), "", "Sess A1_01 Rec01 St1 Rhythm", "", "", "", "", "", ""]];
    var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");

  //get sortId (cue name) column
    var indx = 17;// from headers.indexOf("SORT ID");
    var sortIds = recNotes.map(function(x){
      var testx = x;
      var testxindx = x[indx];
      var testexec = regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1];
      return x[indx];
    });


}
```

Comment: could you show `recNotes` Object?

Comment: @manikantgautam just updated with an example. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your edited code, I managed to make a change that apparently fixed the issue -- make a new RegExp object every loop:

```js
function blah(){
    var tempPref = "Sess "//temp session prefix variable for regexp REPLACE    

    var recNotes = [["", 2, 2, "St1 Rhythm", "A", "AcGtrs&EBass", "top", "53", "", "", "", "N1", "Good Leo Sound", "", "", (new Date(1232449380000)), "", "Sess A1_01 Rec01 St1 Rhythm", "", "", "", "", "", ""],["", 2, 2, "St1 Rhythm", "A", "AcGtrs&EBass", "top", "53", "", "", "", "N1", "Good Leo Sound", "", "", (new Date(1232449380000)), "", "Sess A1_01 Rec01 St1 Rhythm", "", "", "", "", "", ""]];
    var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");

  //get sortId (cue name) column
    var indx = 17;// from headers.indexOf("SORT ID");
    var sortIds = recNotes.map(function(x){
      var testx = x;
      var testxindx = x[indx];
      var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");
      var testexec = regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1];
      return x[indx];
    });
    
    console.log(sortIds);
}

blah();
```

I've seen stuff around the internet talking about the g flag causing issues like this, because the lastIndex flag needs resetting or something like that. I can't say I understand it. [here's a source](https://medium.com/codesnips/js-careful-when-reusing-regex-636b92c6bf07) for example

[edit] after some testing, setting lastIndex on the regexp back to 0 every loop apparently works:

```js
function blah(){
    var tempPref = "Sess "//temp session prefix variable for regexp REPLACE    
    var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");

    var recNotes = [["", 2, 2, "St1 Rhythm", "A", "AcGtrs&EBass", "top", "53", "", "", "", "N1", "Good Leo Sound", "", "", (new Date(1232449380000)), "", "Sess A1_01 Rec01 St1 Rhythm", "", "", "", "", "", ""],["", 2, 2, "St1 Rhythm", "A", "AcGtrs&EBass", "top", "53", "", "", "", "N1", "Good Leo Sound", "", "", (new Date(1232449380000)), "", "Sess A1_01 Rec01 St1 Rhythm", "", "", "", "", "", ""]];
    var regExpCue = new RegExp(tempPref+"(\\w+)","gi");

  //get sortId (cue name) column
    var indx = 17;// from headers.indexOf("SORT ID");
    var sortIds = recNotes.map(function(x){
      var testx = x;
      var testxindx = x[indx];
      regExpCue.lastIndex = 0;
      var testexec = regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1];
      return x[indx];
    });
    
    console.log(sortIds);
}

blah();
```

Comment: that got it. not sure how i'd ever have got to that answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's two possible issues here, but it's impossible to tell which one is your issue because nobody knows what your `recNotes` array looks like

Issue one: `x` is null, so `x[indx]` throws an error.

Issue two: `x[indx]` is null, so `regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1]` throws an error. `regExpCue.exec(x[indx])` returns null, so you're doing `(null)[1]`, which errors

Comment: `indx` is definitely not null but `x` may well be. I thought i could test for this by wrapping the return in `if(x[1]){}` but that doesn't help either

Comment: This is more weird. If i put in line before to test the regex i can see its fine but then when exact;y the same thing is run in the `return` it fails. `      var testexec = regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1];
      return regExpCue.exec(x[indx])[1];`